# Div invisível com pointer-events: none é uma boa idéia?

Tags: html, css

Eu tenho uma div, chamada `#dim-bg`, a qual propósito é ofuscar a tela quando uma janela é focada. É um elemento fixado, vazio, invisível, que não se interage com o usuário, e ocupa toda a tela.

Eu tive a ideia de combinar `pointer-events: none` para simular que ela não está ali, sem ter que mexer em `display`, `height` ou `visibility`. A ideia é fazer uma transição em sua opacidade de forma suave.

```
#dim-bg {
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .5s;
}
#dim-bg.visible {
    pointer-events: all; /* previne clicar onde foi ofuscado */
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Abaixo, tenho uma demonstração da funcionalidade.

```js
const dimBgElement = document.getElementById('dim-bg');

function dimBg() {
  dimBgElement.classList.add("visible");
  document.getElementById('topper').classList.add("visible");
}

function undimBg() {
  dimBgElement.classList.remove("visible");
  document.getElementById('topper').classList.remove("visible");
}
```

```css
#dim-bg {
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: opacity .5s cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
}

#dim-bg.visible {
  opacity: .8;
  pointer-events: all;
}


/* código não relatado à postagem */

#topper,
#bottom {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

#topper {
  top: 30px;
  z-index: 5;
  display: none;
}

#topper.visible {
  display: block;
}

#bottom {
  bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="dim-bg"></div>
<h1 style="text-align: center">
  É possível interagir com isso
</h1>
<div id="topper">
  <button onclick="undimBg()">
    Clique para voltar ao normal
  </button>
</div>
<div id="bottom">
  <button onclick="dimBg()">
    Clique para ofuscar o fundo
  </button>
</div>
```

O conteúdo que fica por baixo de `#dim-bg` inclui botões, textos, imagens, as vezes animações ou vídeos. Não quero usar JavaScript para simular os efeitos de animação.

Minha dúvida é: tenho a performance geral reduzida por ter uma div invisível por cima de tudo? Há alguma contra indicação em fazer isso?

> Minha dúvida surgiu depois de ler [essa notícia](https://tech.hindustantimes.com/tech/news/google-denies-altering-youtube-code-to-slow-down-microsoft-edge-story-8OElzy4dk7trSwokQmDtBK.html), a qual foi publicada há bastante tempo, mas me deixou com uma pulga atrás da orelha.

Comment: Primeiro de tudo, você está tendo problemas de performance? Provavelmente não, certo? Então não tem muito motivo para se preocupar, mesmo que tenha uma forma de se fazer melhor, a diferença será ínfima, dificilmente você conseguiria mensurar, além disso, pode variar de navegador para navegador e entre suas versões. Mas, se você realmente quer fazer da melhor forma possível, provavelmente o ideal é você não manter essa div renderizada sempre, quando precisar, adicione ela ao DOM, quando não precisar mais, a remova

Answer (score -3):

> Minha dúvida é: tenho a performance geral reduzida por ter uma div invisível por cima de tudo? Há alguma contra indicação em fazer isso?

Resposta curta: Sim. Mas é praticamente ínfima. Quanto mais DOM Nodes você tiver em seu documento, mais coisa pra baixar. O que diminui a performance caso esteja usando divs vazias em todo lugar e seu site seja complexo.
Esse artigo explica bem isso:

[Don't fear empty divs](https://www.coryetzkorn.com/blog/dont-fear-empty-divs)

E esse do StackOverflow também esclarece bastante:

[Are empty divs bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14182383/are-empty-divs-bad)

No artigo recomendam usar pseudoelementos (:before, :after) pra resolver o problema. Veja se consegue resolver. Se não, use divs vazias mesmo.

> Minha dúvida surgiu depois de ler essa notícia, a qual foi publicada há bastante tempo, mas me deixou com uma pulga atrás da orelha.

Sobre a notícia:
Basicamente, a Google tava se aproveitando de alguns problemas no software da Microsoft. Nesse [artigo](https://mspoweruser.com/google-claims-edge-slowing-empty-div-was-just-a-bug/) eles disseram que resolveram o problema no Windows 10.

> Joshua Bakita wrote:
> I very recently worked on the Edge team, and one of the reasons we decided to end EdgeHTML was because Google kept making changes to its sites that broke other browsers, and we couldn’t keep up. For example, they recently added a hidden empty div over YouTube videos that causes our hardware acceleration fast-path to bail (should now be fixed in Win10 Oct update). Prior to that, our fairly state-of-the-art video acceleration put us well ahead of Chrome on video playback time on battery, but almost the instant they broke things on YouTube, they started advertising Chrome’s dominance over Edge on video-watching battery life. What makes it so sad, is that their claimed dominance was not due to ingenious optimization work by Chrome, but due to a failure of YouTube. On the whole, they only made the web slower.

Então, vá e escreva seu código sem se preocupar.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).